# Adding "nofollow" Twitter Widget

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the standard follow me widget code supplied by Twitter:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/mysite?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-screen-name="false" data-show-count="true">Follow @mysite</a><script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

However I have not been able to add rel="nofollow" to this.

How can I do that?

Please note that I have tried the following already but it does not work:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/mysite?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-screen-name="false" data-show-count="true" rel="nofollow">Follow @mysite</a><script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work?

Comment: Why do you think it's not working? It won't follow this link https://twitter.com/mysite?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw from now on (if it's nowhere else or has allways the rel=nofollow), but it won't clear it from the indexed sites yet

Comment: If you use a add on such as NoFollow Simple with chrome you can see that the no follow is not working.